# Is there any way to type cast value of enum column in a joined table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, enums

I have the following models:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations
end
```

When I run the following query,

```
@people = Person
  .select('`user`.`name`, `conversations`.`status` AS conversation_status')
  .joins(:conversations)

@people.map &:conversation_status
# => [1, 1, 0]
```

I get the values of `conversation_status` un-typecasted because the returned records are instances of the `Person` model, but the `enum` is defined on `Conversation`. I was wondering if there was a way to type cast an `enum` column's value manually. I can do the following to type cast the values:

```
@people.map do |person|
  Conversation.statuses.find { |name, i| i == person.conversation_status }.first
end
# => ['archived', 'archived', 'active']
```

but it seems a bit awkward. Is there an official/rails/less awkward way of getting there?

Digging into the source code, I found that there is an `ActiveRecord::Enum::EnumType` instance that can `deserialize` the value for me, but I  did not find any public way to fetch it.